# React: condition based on url (image)

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, styles

I have 2 pictures,
and I want to make a condition if he is a man bring him this picture and if he is a woman bring him the second picture
and if he is different from the two then he will not present anything

```
import Female from '../images/Me.png';
import male from '../images/Daniel.png';

style={{backgroundImage:props.gender === 'Male' ? `url(${male})`: 
null,backgroundImage:props.gender === 'Female' ? `url(${Female})`: null }}
```

**I understand because I gave null so he overrides it and it will not show me the Male in life but I did not find another way how to realize it**

Comment: Instead of null, you can pass `male` right? `backgroundImage: props.gender === "Female" ? `url(${Female})` : `url(${male})`;`

Comment: True, but it will also bring me some that are different from Female and not necessarily Male

Comment: You can define a function for rendering the images and pass that to `style` tag.  Something like this `style = (gender) => { if (conditon) return img }....<Tag style={style(props.gender)} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this way:

```
style={{backgroundImage: !!props.gender ? (props.gender === 'Male' ? `url(${male})`: 
`url(${Female})`) : null }}
```

If props.gender is truthy then check male or not? If gender not specified(falsy) then it will be null.

The other way you can do it by stricting the value yourself.

```
style={{backgroundImage: ["Male","Female"].includes(props.gender) ? (props.gender === 'Male' ? `url(${male})`: 
    `url(${Female})`) : null }}
```

This will check the value of props.gender is either male or female first otherwise it will be null.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still does not help that you have not set conditions here on the female
So anything other than male is accepted

Comment: I updated my answers.  Please check now